# Vix, событие onClick на кнопку

Tags: javascript

Имеется ссылка на сайте, созданном на Vix.com.
Нужно прикрутить к этой ссылке код метрики и google analytics, такие как yaCounter и gtag().
Код самой метрики и аналитики подключается в теге `head`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
```

Вот код click

```
$w.onReady(function () {
    //TODO: write your page related code here...

});

export function button1_click(event, $w) {
    //Add your code for this event here: 
    yaCounter111111111.reachGoal('kupit_diab');gtag('event', 'buy_line', {'event_category': 'button'}); return true;
}
```

но если кликнуть по кнопке, то выдаёт ошибку
`ReferenceError: yaCounter11111111 is not defined`
`Uncaught ReferenceError: yaCounter11111111 is not defined`

Как избавиться от этой ошибки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "yaCounter111111111.reachGoal" и " yaCounter11111111 is not defined" c 1-ми не напутано?